# How to fix fsockopen error?

Tags: php, fsockopen

Please help me to fix my code

```
$fp = fsockopen("projecthoneypot.org/statistics.php", 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);

if ($fp) {
    $url = "/";

    fputs($fp, "GET $url HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {projecthoneypot.org/statistics.php}\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");
    $resp = '';

    while(!feof($fp)) {
        $resp .= fgets($fp, 1024);
    }

    echo "$resp";
}
```

I always get  this error

```
Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/xxx/public_html/xxx.php on line 3

Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to projecthoneypot.org\statistics.php:80 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known) in /home/xxx/public_html/xxx.php on line 3
```

What is the problem please?

Comment: Possible duplicate question: [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661546/php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service-not-known)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With fsockopen, you need to pass only the ip/hostname.

Try changing:

```
$fp = fsockopen("projecthoneypot.org/statistics.php", 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);
// to
$fp = fsockopen("projecthoneypot.org", 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);
```

As part of your HTTP request, Host: should just be projecthoneypot.org, not projecthoneypot.org/statistics.php.

$url should probably be /statistics.php

Comment: Just voted this up (someone had previously voted it down) as it's the correct answer

Comment: You are a Great Man !! Thank you very much drew010. Regards