# PHP stream_socket_client() Warning

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings

I am building a new WordPress site for a client and all of a sudden today I am seeing this error at the top of the screen.  I have never seen this before.  Any ideas what could be causing this to happen now?  Also how to fix it?

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/wp-includes/class-http.php on line 787

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://www.MY-DOMAIN.com:80 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known) in /var/www/wp-includes/class-http.php on line 787
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like whatever is at `www.MY-DOMAIN.com:80` is not resolving properly. If you know what that is look at your `hosts` file and your DNS configuration. If you don't know what that is check all your code carefully for a hack.

Comment: maybe a plugin is causing this due to a missconfiguration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php\_network\_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661546/php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service-not-known). [There's 231 of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php_network_getaddresses%3A+getaddrinfo+failed). Why do you think the image of the site would help with a php warning?

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if you are using a VM but when I had this error I resolved it by adding an entry to my hosts file in my vagrant machine that pointed back to localhost.

```
127.0.0.1 www.MY-DOMAIN.com
```

Comment: I'm using Docker under AWS BeanStalk and it worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Sorted for me now also :-)