# subscribe on mailchimp in php

Tags: php, mailchimp

I trying to save the record of the subscriber to mail chimp in php, but i'm getting this error of which i don't understand:

**fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.**

I'm using MCAPI class version 1.3

here is my code to save:

```
    $apikey='d9750fc48519551e22e789c1gthy050a5-fd7'; // Enter your API key
    $api = new MCAPI($apikey);
    $retval = $api->lists();


    $listid='d395e7afr4'; // Enter list Id here

    $fname = $this->stepdata['yourName'];
    $lname = $this->stepdata['yourName'];
    $email = $this->stepdata['yourEmail'];


    // By default this sends a confirmation email - you will not see new          members
    // until the link contained in it is clicked!

    $merge_vars = array('FNAME' => $fname, 'LNAME' => $lname, 'EMAIL' => $email);
    //listSubscribe'=>array("id","email_address","merge_vars","email_type","double_optin","update_existing","replace_interests","send_welcome")
    if($api->listSubscribe($listid, $email, $merge_vars, $email_type='html', $double_optin=false, $update_existing=false, $replace_interests=false, $send_welcome=true ) === true) {

    }
```

This is where the error is pointing at on MCAPI class

```
   ob_start();
    if ($this->secure){
        $sock = fsockopen("ssl://".$host, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    } else {
        $sock = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please check these two link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210099/php-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-no-such-host-is-known. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661546/php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service-not-known

Comment: If that's your real API key, you might want remove it from the code sample and for security, generate a new one.

Comment: @Shervin no it not my real API key thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 0):

If that's a real API Key, you should definitely disable the API Key and generate a new one, but that actually helps answer this question in this case.

The MailChimp libraries use the second part of the API Key to determine [which datacenter to connect to](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/). In this case, the library is going to interpret that as 'fd7', and will try to connect to `fd7.api.mailchimp.com`, which isn't a valid MailChimp datacenter.

I'd re-copy your API key from your dashboard and make sure that the last part looks like 'usX' where X is some number between 1-10.